# Жирные слова должны становиться красного цвета при наведении на сам абзац . Код нужен на js

Tags: javascript

```js
var allbl = document.querySelectorAll(" .some");

allbl.forEach(function(el){
   el.onmouseover = function(){
        this.style.background = "red";
   } 
   el.onmouseout = function(){
        this.style.background = "white";
        allbl.forEach(function(el){       
        });
   }
});
```

```html
Простой <b class="some"  >пример</b> небольшого текста, в <b class="some">котором</b> есть выделенные <b class="some">жирным</b> слова.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: это можно сделать css, без кодирования

Comment: Жирные слова в абзаце, что представлен выше. Жирные слова должны становиться красного цвета при наведении на сам абзац.  У меня получается ,только одно слово выделить красным.

Comment: 1) Не закрыт тег( ошибка в синтаксисе)
2) Почему бы не сделать при помощи ccs и не лезть в js?

Comment: у вас сейчас обработчик прикручен к словам. Надо ховер сделать на абзац, и внутри искать уже слова и им менять цвет. Исправьте логику кода, в целом все нужные вещи вы знаете как писать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов как реализовать есть множество.

У Вас ошибка в том, что событие вешаете на элементы `.some` а нужно на всю строку.

Чтоб повесить на всю строку нам нужна оббертка (в моем примере тег p)

При наведении для всех дочерних элементов строки ищем элементы `.some` и меняем цвет на противоположный.

Так же, вы писали что цвет нужно менять текста а не фона а у вас меняется фон.

```js
var allbl = document.querySelectorAll(".with-js");

function toggle(element) {
  element.style.color = element.style.color === "red" ? "black": "red";
}

allbl.forEach(function(el) {
  const items = el.querySelectorAll(".some")
  el.onmouseover = function() {
    items.forEach(item => {
      toggle(item)
    })
  }
  el.onmouseout = function() {
    items.forEach(item => {
      toggle(item)
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<p class="with-js">
  Простой <b class="some">пример</b> небольшого текста, в <b class="some">котором</b> есть выделенные <b class="some">жирным</b> слова.
</p>
```

Функция toggle добавлена чтоб не дублировать код.

```
element.style.color = element.style.color === "red" ? "black": "red";
```

Такой вид - это упрощенная запись if (вместо if используем [тернарный оператор](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse) `?`)

это равноценно:

```js
function toggle(element) {
  element.style.color = (function() {
    if (element.style.color === "red") {
      return "black"
    } else {
      return "red"
    }
  })()
}
```

Есть еще проще способ - добавлять и удалять класс для строки, а в css через класс дочерним элементам менять цвет.

**UPD** Как указал в комментариях пользователь [teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran):

> вы пишите .forEach( item => toggle(item) ) по сути ваша анонимка просто пробрасывает значение в toggle. сигнатура у нее такая же. так что код можно упростить до .forEach(toggle) –
> teran

Достаточно написать:

```js
var allbl = document.querySelectorAll(".with-js");

function toggle(element) {
  element.style.color = element.style.color === "red" ? "black": "red";
}

allbl.forEach(function(el) {
  const items = el.querySelectorAll(".some")
  el.onmouseover = function() {
    items.forEach(toggle)
  }
  el.onmouseout = function() {
    items.forEach(toggle)
  }
});
```

```html
<p class="with-js">
  Простой <b class="some">пример</b> небольшого текста, в <b class="some">котором</b> есть выделенные <b class="some">жирным</b> слова.
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает.

Comment: `item => toggle(item)` тут собственно лишнее, просто `toggle` параметром цикла

Comment: @teran, не совсем понял, как передать итерируемый объект?

Comment: @АлексДемалио Хорошо бы поблагодарить автора и галочкой (ниже треугольника у ответа)

Comment: @Greg-- ну вы пишите `.forEach( item => toggle(item) )` по сути ваша анонимка просто пробрасывает значение в `toggle`. сигнатура у нее такая же. так что код можно упростить до `.forEach(toggle)`

Comment: @teran теперь понял, добавил ваш ответ

Answer (score 1):

```css
p:hover .some{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<p>Простой <b class="some"  >пример</b> небольшого текста.</p> 
<p>В <b class="some">котором</b> есть выделенные <b class="some">жирным</b> слова.</p>
```

Если вдруг понадобится решение без использования js, а только с помощью css.